# Can I safely move Scrapy's HttpCacheMiddleware closer to the engine?

Tags: scrapy

The site that I am scraping occasionally returns fake responses with error code 200. So I need to use a custom http caching policy that prevents code 200 responses with a certain substring in the response body to end up in the httpcache.

Scrapy's default middleware order is below. With this order, the httpcache middleware does not have access to the uncompressed document body yet (gzip compressed).

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware': 300,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware': 350,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': 500,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 550,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl.AjaxCrawlMiddleware': 560,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware': 580,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 590,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': 600,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': 700,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 750,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats': 850,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware': 900,
}
```

Can I safely move the HttpCacheMiddleware closer to the engine like in the below example? Or will this cause unwanted side effects on other middlewares?

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware': 300,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware': 350,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': 500,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 550,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl.AjaxCrawlMiddleware': 560,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware': 580,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware': 585,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 590,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': 600,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': 700,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 750,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats': 850,
}
```

Comment: I can't really see what could break here but I think it would be safer to move the compression middleware up instead since it's a much more simple pipeline :) I'm honestly not sure why `HttpCompressionMiddleware` isn't last in the default settings. It might be worth opening up an issue or a merge request!

Comment: Agreed. Was wondering too. Where would you put it?

Comment: at the very end, 910 for example.

Comment: Wonderful. Thx dir yout advice. Worked as expected.

Comment: Granitosaurus, please consider writing a response out of your comments.